# MS Word: How to show/hide or disable/enable multiple content controls depending on a boolean value (e.g. checkbox)?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Want to make a shared **MS Word** document among persons who might attend an event or not. That is, if a certain person checks the checkbox of attending the event additional content controls should appear (or should get enabled) for selecting the type of hotel room, number of nights to reserve, whether it's vegan or not etc. When the person changes its mind and decide not to attend (clear the checkbox) the additional content controls should get hided (or disabled again).

The `IF` field not the best here as (as far as I know) just plain text can be added to `true` and `false` branches.

Would avoid **Excel,** if possible. (Though not exclude if I have no chances to do this in Word.)

Any thoughts?

Comment: That's possible - but you have to use VBA for that

Comment: @Ike Do you mean that checkboxes in MS Word have something similar to event handlers in Delphi? And when the checkbox changes its state I can programatically change (hide or disable) the appropriate elements by implementing an event handler?

Comment: Yes, content controls do have event handlers - and there is a checkbox content control as well

Comment: @Ike Thanks! Though my VBA skills are not that advancesd I think – based on my Delphi/C++ knowledge – this should not be difficult!

Comment: Another hint: look for the repeating section content control to use for adding new rows to your table based on the defined structure of content controls per cell

Comment: You should use a Word template (.dotm format) containing one or more Quick Part Building Blocks for this. The Quick Part could, for example, consist of a table containing all the additional content controls and text. If the use checks the checkbox, you'd simply insert the Quick Part (i.e. the table). If they then un-check the checkbox, you'd simply delete the table.